# Cannot recognize a method I created in RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I created my own class called RecyclerviewAdapter.java that extends `RecyclerView.Adapter<>`, and I created a method in that class

```
public void setItemCount(int i){
    size=i;
}
```

My `RecyclerView` works, and I want user to be able to set how many items to be displayed in RecyclerView. In MainActivity, when I call `adapter.setItemCount(2)`, it says `Cannot resolve method 'setItemCount' in 'Adapter'`, also `Method 'setItemCount(int)' is never used`. I don't know how to solve it.
Here are my files.
MainActivity.java

```
RecyclerView recycler;
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager;
ArrayList<RecyclerviewItem> list=new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new RecyclerviewItem(R.drawable.hoversfw,"Title","Description"));
    manager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    adapter=new RecyclerviewAdapter(list);
    recycler=findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recycler.setLayoutManager(manager);
    recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
if(!count.getText().toString().equals("")) {
    int c= Integer.parseInt(count.getText().toString());
    adapter.setItemCount(c);
}
```

RecyclerviewAdapter.java

```
public class RecyclerviewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerviewAdapter.RecyclerviewHolder> {
private ArrayList<RecyclerviewItem> list;
private int size;

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerviewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item,parent,false);
    RecyclerviewHolder holder=new RecyclerviewHolder(v);
    return holder;
}


public RecyclerviewAdapter(ArrayList<RecyclerviewItem>mlist){
    list=mlist;
    size=1;
}

public void setItemCount(int i){
    size=i;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerviewHolder holder, int position) {
    RecyclerviewItem item=list.get(position);
    holder.image.setImageResource(item.getImageResource());
    holder.title.setText(item.getTitle());
    holder.description.setText(item.getDescription());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return size;
}

public static class RecyclerviewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public ImageView image;
    public TextView title;
    public TextView description;

    public RecyclerviewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        image=itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        title=itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        description=itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
    }
}
}
```

RecyclerviewItem.java

```
public class RecyclerviewItem {
private int imageResource;
private String title;
private String description;

public RecyclerviewItem(int mimageResource, String mtitle, String mdescription){
    imageResource=mimageResource;
    title=mtitle;
    description=mdescription;
}

public int getImageResource(){
    return imageResource;
}

public String getTitle(){
    return title;
}

public String getDescription(){
    return description;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring `RecyclerView` Adapter with `RecyclerView.Adapter` although it should be `RecyclerviewAdapter`

[`RecyclerView.Adapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter) is an SDK class, but `RecyclerviewAdapter` is yours.

Comment: My recyclerview actually works like normal because `RecyclerviewAdapter` extends `RecyclerView.Adapter`. It's just I can't use a method I made inside RecyclerviewAdapter.

Comment: Just replace `RecyclerView.Adapter ` with `RecyclerviewAdapter` in the line `RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;`

Comment: It worked. The tutorial I watched was doing this so I thought there would be no problem there.